# OpenCV - Metric representation in `reprojectImageTo3D()`

Tags: opencv, image-processing, camera-calibration, stereoscopy

On my left camera, right camera and stereo calibration; I've indicated the size of the square

`0.025 (25 millimeters)`

So I get the points in 3D using `reprojectImageTo3D(disp, Q)`

```
disp = stereo.compute(dstL, dstR).astype(np.float32) / 16.0
disp = abs(disp-min_disp)/num_disp
```

I got Q from `stereoRectify`

I took a picture of a box 2.5 - 3 ft away from the stereo camera and retrieved the `xyz` coordinates of a point lying on it. Its `Z` value is `140.8764`

How should I interpret that?

My `Q` looks like this

```
|1, 0, 0, -454.05216408|
|0, 1, 0, -231.55072975|
|0, 0, 0, 816.20826814 |
|0, 0, 13.79730561, -0 |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having used units consistently within all respective calibration functions (in this case metres), then the output from `cv::reprojectImageTo3D` should have similar units (here again metres).

In `Q`, the value at (3,2) is the inverse of the camera baseline value (here `0.0725 m` which makes sense). Values at (0,3) and (1,3) are the principal point's xy-coordinates (roughly the middle of the image; again making sense) and (2,3) is the relative focal length (with respect to the image width).

Don't scale the disparity. So comment this line:

```
#disp = abs(disp-min_disp)/num_disp
```

Comment: When I comment that line in `python`, when I imshow() it, it only shows white.

Comment: where did you get the `0.0725m`? im so sorry, im having a hard time on this! thanks for your help

Comment: `1/13.797=0.0725`, If you wan't to show the disparity map, compute its minimum and maximum and scale it to [0,255] 8bpp for visualization, but use the original for the reprojection.

Comment: i see! so all the values that i'm getting is in meters? right?

Comment: Yes, all values that have unit are meters. Some are relative though (as the focallength).